# does mallet have a GUI?

Tags: user-interface, machine-learning, text-mining, mallet

Has anyone seen a GUI for [Mallet](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu)?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/topic-modeling-tool/

you might also be interested in:

http://electricarchaeology.ca/2011/11/11/topic-modeling-with-the-java-gui-gephi/